# React Flow - Custom Connectors

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am using react flow library to create a flow diagram. React Flow: https://reactflow.dev

Is there a way in react-flow to connect nodes as shown in above picture.  I have a requirement to connect Node 1 (top) to Node 2 (top). I am unable to find any suitable solution. :(

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the line to be of `type` `"step"` and specify the target and source on node 1 and node 2 to be top.

```
const initialElements = [
 {
  id: '1',
  sourcePosition: "top",
  data: { label: "Node 1" },
  position: { x: 0, y: 50 },
 },
 {
  id: '2',
  targetPosition: "top",
  data: { label: "Node 2" },
  position: { x: 300, y: 50 },
 },
 {
  id: "1-2",
  type: "step",
  source: "1",
  target: "2",
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://Value%20must%20be%20omitted%20for%20boolean%20attributes) you should be able to set `connectionMode` to `loose` and then you can set target to target connections (and have your targets align to top).

> connectionMode: default: 'strict'. Possible values are 'strict' (only source to target connections are possible) or 'loose' (source to source and target to target connections are allowed)